# Easiest way to visualize 10,000 shaded boxes in 3D

Tags: visualization, 3d, data-visualization

I have a simple task: I have 10,000 3D boxes, each with a x,y,z, width, height, depth, rotation, and color. I want to throw them into a 3D space, visualize it, and let the user fly through it using the mouse. Is there an easy way to put this together?

Comment: Do you have a language and graphics library you are using? Or is your question about what language and graphics library to use?

Comment: I have no restrictions! I can use ANYTHING. I'm looking for suggestions.

Comment: I found this good list comparing 3D Game engines: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Game_Programming_in_Python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One easy way of doing this using recent (v 3.2) OpenGL would be:

- make an array with 8 vertices (the corners of a cube), give them coordinates on the unit cube, that is from (-1,-1, -1) to (1, 1, 1)
- create a [vertex buffer object](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_vbo.html)
- use `glBufferData` to get your array into the vertex buffer
- bind the vertex buffer
- create, set up, and bind any textures that you may want to use (skip this if you don't use textures)
- create a vertex shader which applies a transform matrix that is read from "some source" (see below) according to the value of `gl_InstanceID`
- compile the shader, link the program, bind the program
- set up the instance transform data (see below) for all cube instances
- depending on what method you use to communicate the transform data, you may draw everything in one batch, or use several batches
- call `glDrawElementsInstanced` *N* number of times with `count` set to as many elements as will fit into one batch
- if you use several batches, update the transform data in between
- the vertex shader applies the transform in addition to the normal MVP stuff

To communicate the per-cube transform data, you have several alternatives, among them are:

- [uniform buffer objects](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glBindBuffer.xml), you have a *guaranteed minimum* of 4096 values, respectively 256 4x4 matrices, but you can query the actual value
- [texture buffer objects](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/), again you have a *guaranteed minimum* of 65536 values, respectively 4096 4x4 matrices (but usually something much larger, my elderly card can do 128,000,000 values, you should query the actual value)
- manually set uniforms for each batch, this does not need any "buffer" stuff, but is most probably somewhat slower

**Alternatively:** Use [pseudo-instancing](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/SDK/9.5/Samples/DEMOS/OpenGL/src/glsl_pseudo_instancing/docs/glsl_pseudo_instancing.pdf) which will work even on hardware that does not support instancing directly. It is not as elegant and very slightly slower, but it does the job.

Comment: Gosh, that does not seem easy.

Comment: Well, you can just transform and draw them all individually using `glRotate`. `glTranslate`, and `glDrawElements`. That's _easy_, but it does not scale well to 10,000+ instances. Pseudo-instancing (read the link) is still comparatively easy.

Comment: Still seems like a lot more code than I was thinking of doing. I'm looking right now at Panda3D and have modified the Disco-Lights demo to display 10,000 moving spheres. I need to figure out how to create my own box, though, rather than using a sphere that gets loaded. So I guess I need to read the manual. That's tonight's project. I will post the code when I am done.

Comment: I coded up the 10,000 objects. You are correct. It was *easy* but it did not scale above 10,000 instances. But it was sufficient for what I needed to do.